# Visual Studio 2022 - How to turn off new AI red highlighting with arrow and tab replace feature - NOT intellisense entirely?

Tags: visual-studio, artificial-intelligence, visual-studio-2022, autosuggest

I've wasted almost an hour trying to find the setting to turn off the new AI autocomplete feature that was released in the last two months, between October 2022 and now.
I do NOT want to turn off intellisense entirely, only the new feature that highlights chunks in red and shows an arrow to replace the text with an auto suggestion.

This feature has not worked correctly since it was implemented for me.  If you type fast, it's constantly trying to overwrite what you just typed, and it's constantly prompting for changes - even after hitting the escape key and rejecting them repeatedly.

Can someone please tell me the name of this specific feature, and how to disable it in VS2022?

Thank you.

[image]

I've spent an hour trying to find the release notes on this specific feature and have only found how to entirely disable intellisense, which is not what I want.

I still want the drop-down intellisense prompts as I'm typing, I do not want this red highlighting with the tab to replace arrow and suggestions that keeps popping up repeatedly after I've already written my code.

Comment: I rolled my install back to 17.3.7 because this problem is blocking me from using VS17.4 effectively - I can't fight with AI half the time I'm trying to type.  If anyone knows how to disable this in 17.4 please reply!

Comment: Yeah this red and green mess of a "feature" is driving me insane!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are attempting to write SQL strings in Visual Studio 17.4 and running into formatting issues with the red highlighting on intellicode, I recommend rolling back to 17.3.7 until a new update is available.

This [dev community report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/The-red-AI-highlighting-with-the-arrow-a/10228166) has been acknowledged by Microsoft and hopefully a fix will be available soon as it's stamped pending release 1/17/23.

Still no word if this is baked directly into intellicode itself or is a separate feature.

This feature can now be turned off completely in VS17.5 under the name 'inline diff view'.

[image]